# filtering in sharepoint caml

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml

Below I have the view which i have in the list schema.The issue is that it never picks the where clause.It displays the order by clause correctly when I go to modify the view but not the where clause which should show up in the filter section.I also tried ceating a view in UI and then through sharepoint manager got the schema and then created a view but still does not work.Am I doing something wrong here.

```
<View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Tab 1" DefaultView="FALSE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="T1.aspx">
<Toolbar Type="Standard" />
<XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
<RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
<Query>
<OrderBy Override="TRUE">
<FieldRef Name="Test1" />
<FieldRef Name="Test2" />
</OrderBy>
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="Test3"/>
<Value Type="Text">1</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Attachments"></FieldRef>
<FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
<FieldRef Name="Test1"></FieldRef>
<FieldRef Name="Test2"></FieldRef>
<FieldRef Name="Test3"></FieldRef>

<FieldRef Name="Audience"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>

<ParameterBindings>
<ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
<ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
</ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put Where clause before the Order By Clause.

I am not 100% sure but give it a try